# RedHawk Building Blocks

Tags: redhawksdr

The GitHub repository has what appears to be a number of building blocks useful for developers but most have little or no description of their function in the README.md or other files (that I can find).  Is there any documentation anywhere else. Other than guessing from the package title, how do I learn what they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description for the components and their functionality can be found in each component's SPD file between the `<description`> and `</description`> tags

Comment: Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place, but I do not find a SPD file in any of the components I have looked in.  A very few have SVD but it only describes the changes and not the components functionality.

Comment: Are you looking on github.com/RedhawkSDR?  Every component is required to have an SPD file (e.g. for the whitenoise component it is called whitenoise.spd.xml) in REDHAWK.  If you download one of the components and open it in the IDE, you can select the component's SPD file and its description will appear in an easy to read way.  If you view the raw XML, it's a bit harder to read but still helpful

Comment: Oh.  That helps.  I find many that do have the spd.xml.  Many appear to be part of a larger package "basic-components" which does not have an SPD, but appears to just be a collection.  All of the components in basic-components have SPDs but none of the other packages (about 1/3 of the packages) that I see (e.g., burstioInterfaces, framework-bulkiointerfaces, librtisdr, dsp, eclipse-mil.jpeojtrs.sca, ...) have SPDs and are apparently not RedHawk components but it is still not clear what they are.

Comment: The basic-components package is for convenience, allowing you to pull all of the basic-components at once.  It's not a component, nor are the burstio, bulkio, librtlsdr, dsp, eclipse, etc.  Burstio, bulkio, librtlsdr, and dsp are all libraries which aid the developer in some way and so do not need SPD files.  The eclipse directories are part of the IDE plugins and should not (generally) be downloaded separately.  Only Components, Devices, and Shared Packages have SPD files that specify to the REDHAWK framework how the Resource (parent of Components and Devices) should be executed